# Access different blocks (submatrices) of a symbolic block matrix in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I am a newbie to Python.

I wondered if there is any way to access different elements of a symbolic block matrix using the `sympy` module.

For example, I have generated the following code, I would want to see `C_11+C_12` by using `C[0]` but instead I see `C_11[0, 0] + C_13[0, 0]`

```
from sympy import *


C_11 = MatrixSymbol('C_11', 5, 5)

C_12 = MatrixSymbol('C_12', 5, 3)

C_13 = MatrixSymbol('C_13', 5, 5)

C_21 = C_12.T 

C_22 = MatrixSymbol('C_22', 3, 3)

C_23 = MatrixSymbol('C_23', 3, 5)

C_31 = C_13.T

C_32 = C_23.T

C_33 = MatrixSymbol('C_33', 5, 5)

C = BlockMatrix([[C_11+C_13, C_12, C_13],
                 [C_21, C_22, C_23],
                 [C_31, C_32, C_33]])

C

C[0]
```

Comment: hi @abk; please provide a minimal verifiable complete example and I'm sure someone will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hi@kevinkayaks, thanks very much for the link. I just need to figure out how to insert portions of the code in my question

Comment: You can indent four spaces on every line once it's already typed, or you can highlight the code block and hit the { } symbol in the editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (i, j) block of a block matrix C is accessed with `C.blocks[i, j]`. An example:

```
from sympy import *
b = Matrix([1, 2, 4, 8])
C = BlockMatrix([[b, 3*b], [5*b, 7*b]])
print(C.blocks[0, 1])
```

prints `Matrix([[3], [6], [12], [24]])`.

Other potentially useful properties of BlockMatrix objects can be found by reading the [source](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/matrices/expressions/blockmatrix.html#BlockMatrix). Not all of them are mentioned in the documentation.